# How to use css property jquery popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want that whenever i click on button(Dialog) then popup with html should open(inside somediv tag) ,Popup is opening but i want to increase
width of popup and move to left side of screen instead of middile,How can i do this ?
Here is my code

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openDialog() {
            $("#somediv").dialog({
                modal: true
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<style>
    #somediv {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="somediv">

        <div class="row clear">
            <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <div class="border text-center">
                    <p class="black-text">$50</p>
                    <h2 class="black-text light">1 Month</h2>
                    <p>5 Job Postings</p>
                    <p>Resume Search</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="border text-center">
                    <p class="black-text">$140</p>
                    <h2 class="black-text light">3 Month</h2>
                    <p>10 Job Postings</p>
                    <p>Resume Search</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="border text-center">
                    <p class="black-text">$400</p>
                    <h2 class="black-text light">Annual</h2>
                    <p>Unlimited Job Postings</p>
                    <p>Resume Search</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="openDialog();">Dialog</a>
</body>
```

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-minWidth -> You can get all the needed settings for the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifies where the dialog should be displayed when opened. The dialog will handle collisions such that as much of the dialog is visible as possible.

The `of` property defaults to the window, but you can specify another element to position against. You can refer to the [jQuery UI Position](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/) utility for more details about the available properties.

Code examples:
Initialize the dialog with the `position` option specified:

```
function openDialog() {
    $("#somediv").dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 500, // or you can have it in %
        height: 400, // or you can have it in %
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: window }
    });
}
```

Note : You can also use css style to adjust the width and height if need to

Comment: How can i increase width of popup(#somediv) ?

Comment: you can have `width` attribute to increase the width, like this `width: 500`, I have updated my answer with `width`

Answer (score 0):

the css you need to increase width and move the modal to left:

```
#somediv{
    width: 50% (or anything of your choice);
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
}
```

Comment: How can i increase width of popup ?

Comment: #divId{
    width: 200px
}

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI dialog provides options to set the dialog position. 
This is the position object you can pass into the dialog constructor -

`{ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }`

Your code should look something like this -

`$("#somediv").dialog({
                modal: true,
                position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: window },
                width: 500
            });`

Refer to jQuery UI documentation [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position).

Comment: How can i increase width of popup ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery UI Position](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/) or set the `position` property when opening the dialog:

```
function openDialog() {
    $("#somediv").dialog({
        modal: true,
        position:['left', 20],
    });
}
```

Comment: how can i increase width of popup ?